# What is the best practice to set parameters to object and avoid duplicated code?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm working in a project that have some entities, and to set the entities attributes, we have a lot of code like this:

```
    public void recordLogFile(int fileSize, int fileHeight, Long idFile) {

    try {

        LogFileEntity logEntity = new LogFileEntity();
        logEntity.setFileSize(fileSize);
        logEntity.setFileHeight(fileHeight);
        logEntity.setFile(FileEntity.find(idFile));
        logEntity.setStatus(LogStatus.SUCESS);
        logEntity.setType(LogType.NORMAL);
        logEntity.persist();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        some log code
    }

}
```

There are a lot of classes that need to persist the log file entity, but in some cases we have different values on attributes. For example LogStatus.FAIL LogType.OLD, and we have a repeated piece of code only changing the value.

What is the best approach to make this better??

Thanks !!!

Comment: I would suggest the Factory method pattern.  You can pass in parameters for status and type and have the method return a LogFileEntity object for you.

Comment: @Joe i think that factory pattern is very useful.. thanks

Comment: 1. Extract to method 2. Write builders with defaults

Comment: Consider cohesion of `recordLogFile()`. What is the name of its class? This method doesn't seem to adhere to the Single Responsibility Principle, which may be the real reason you have duplicated code. It would be useful to see the variants where there is duplication, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a couple of things. The simplest thing is to create objects that are built with default values, and provide constructors to fill out the rest. For example, you have this class `LogFileEntity` which appears to have 5 attributes: `fileSize`, `fileHeight`, `file`, `logStatus`, and `logType`. Let us assume that `LogStatus.SUCESS` and `LogType.NORMAL` are default values. If you set these values in the `LogFileEntity`, the client will not have to set them all the time.  Your class constructor could look something like this:

```
public LogFileEntity()
{
    logStatus = LogStatus.SUCESS;
    logType = LogType.NORMAL;
    // Maybe set other default values
}
```

That said, the best you can do is make use of the [Factory Design Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) to implement this.

Comment: Hi hfontanez... the main thing is to avoid create a lot of methods like recordErrorLogFile and just change the status.. another that change the status and type.. etc...

Comment: There are a range of things you can do. Some more complex than others. For example, a single instance of a log file can change status once created, you could (and should) use the State Pattern to make sure the status (life cycle) of a file could only change from a particular state, to a valid state; depending on context. The same thing can be accomplished with simple "setter" methods, but obviously the simpler solution is more error prone because a client could set the state to an invalid state. Factory pattern solves the problem of creating objects. State pattern solves changing its state.

Comment: BTW, here's the [State Pattern Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/state_pattern.htm). They do a good job keeping the examples simple.  This is a good example on why problem decomposition is important. One of the problems that needs solving deals with creation of objects (LogFileEntity). There are a few creational patterns one could use to solve this problem. Another part of the problem deals with behavior of the object once created. There are several other behavioral design patterns to choose from. I provided you links to two of such patterns.

Comment: @Mr.PaulHenry Over-design is a risk with State pattern. See http://angry-architect.blogspot.ca/2006/08/problems-with-state-pattern.html I think your state logic is probably simple enough NOT to warrant encapsulating it into individual classes. If the code for states and transitions in a switch/case takes one page, it's better than all the complexity of a State class hierarchy, etc. Just because your project has states does note mean you need apply the State pattern.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator over-design is a risk with just about anything you do. The question is more what is the greater risk. There is also a risk of software being too error-prone by allowing clients set states incorrectly. When designing a solution, one must weight all these risks and proceed with the best solution one can come up with. Often riskier solutions have to be implemented for the sake of schedule, budget, team experience, etc. But that is something we cannot debate. Only the OP and his team really know what they are up against. It is up to them to decide what's best.

Comment: Can you elaborate how clients are protected from setting states incorrectly in the State pattern solution @hfontanez? Even if you're claiming encapsulating state info in an object is some kind of protection, you can still do that with a single object. As for the state pattern, nothing stops a client from incorrectly calling the wrong transition (method) assuming those methods are visible to the client. I've never seen any documentation about how the State pattern (GoF) provides this kind of protection.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator the State Pattern helps implementing what is known as a Finite-State Machine (FSM), where an object's transition is predicated on its current state and context (and stimulus received). I have used this pattern to implement Wizards among other things.  You wrote "you can still do that with a single object." And you will be correct. However, it is not a matter of what you can do, is a matter of how it is best implemented. Like the old saying goes "there are 1,000 ways to skin a cat."

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Additionally, the GoF documentation describes how this proection is achieved. The GoF define ***Context*** as a class used by clients of the state design pattern. **Clients do not access the state objects directly**. The Context class holds a concrete state object that provides the behavior according to its current state. If you want to discuss this further, we can start a chat.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest resolution to your immediate issue is to add an overloaded method that takes the additional parameters:

```
    public void recordLogFile(int fileSize, int fileHeight, Long idFile) {
        recordLogFile(fileSize, fileHeight, idFile, LogStatus.SUCESS, LogType.NORMAL);
    }

    public void recordLogFile(int fileSize, int fileHeight, Long idFile,
        LogStatus status, LogType type) {

        try {

            LogFileEntity logEntity = new LogFileEntity();
            logEntity.setFileSize(fileSize);
            logEntity.setFileHeight(fileHeight);
            logEntity.setFile(FileEntity.find(idFile));
            logEntity.setStatus(status);
            logEntity.setType(type);
            logEntity.persist();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // some log code
        }

    }
```